# Delayed Job giving a undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

Delayed job (2.1.4) is working perfectly on my development machine, sending emails with gay abandon - however it is failing miserably when running on my server using Apache/Passenger(3.0.7). Rails 3.0.7 and ruby 1.9.2 on both btw.

I have seen that there is a problem when using thin where the job is created like this:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMailer
object: !ruby/object:Class UserMailer
```

when it should read:

```
--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMailer
object: !ruby/class UserMailer
```

Mine are created correctly on my development machine, but the wrong way when created on the server.

Has anyone else had this problem, where should I start looking?

Stacktrace:

```
{undefined method `standard_message' for #<Class:0xc6ad054>
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/performable_mailer.rb:6:in `perform'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `block (2 levels) in run'\n
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:57:in `timeout'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `block in run'\n
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in `block in work_off'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in start'\n
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:309:in `realtime'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `block in start'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `loop'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:104:in `run'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:83:in `block in run_process'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:249:in `call'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:249:in `block in start_proc'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:199:in `call'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/daemonize.rb:199:in `call_as_daemon'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:253:in `start_proc'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/application.rb:293:in `start'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/controller.rb:70:in `run'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons.rb:195:in `block in run_proc'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `call'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons/cmdline.rb:109:in `catch_exceptions'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/daemons-1.1.3/lib/daemons.rb:194:in `run_proc'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:81:in `run_process'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:75:in `block in daemonize'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in `times'\n
/home/safrea/site/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/delayed_job-2.1.4/lib/delayed/command.rb:73:in `daemonize'\n
script/delayed_job:5:in `<main>'
```

Comment: I don't know why the job would be created differently (perhaps because of the way classes are blown away and reloaded in dev) but what error do you actually get? Have you tried running locally in "production" mode? Perhaps post a stacktrace.

Comment: I have the problem upgrading from 3.0.6 to 3.0.9 Rails. 3.0.6 (with 1.9.2) works fine.

Comment: My solution is to redefine 'taguri' function at the handler class.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6286432/delayed-job-in-rails-failing/6776593#6776593

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have managed to fix this.

I created a setup_load_paths.rb a few weeks ago when bundler stopped working for some reason. This meant that the gemfile was being loaded everywhere, except by passenger. This messed up the call to YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "syck" which seems to be what mucked up the saving of the object.

I removed the setup_load_paths and everything is working nicely now.

Comment: I have been debugging this issue for quite some time then stumbled across this! Excellent!

Comment: but what does this setup_load_paths.rb does? I don't have it but still experiencing this problem. What was in it?

Answer (score 0):

If using the Syck parser doesn't seem to work (like mentioned in Marc's answer), try using the psych parser instead.

```
YAML::ENGINE.yamler = "psych"
```