# Undefined method and bad serialization with delayed job on lion

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am getting some odd behavior on a newly set up mac with os x lion.  Our app runs fine in the development environment locally but in the test environment delayed job is not serializing correctly.  On my other machine (snow leopard) everything works fine from the same branch & commit.  Below you will see the job and error.

Any ideas on what would cause this?

BTW, I have no setup_load_paths.rb file.  The solution on a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301430/delayed-job-giving-a-undefined-method-error) won't work.

```
#<Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job:0x007fe3771343b0> {
            :id => 1,
      :priority => 0,
      :attempts => 0,
       :handler => "--- !ruby/struct:Delayed::PerformableMethod \nobject: !ruby/object:Class User\nmethod_name: :update_listed_package_states_for\nargs: \n- 2\n",
    :last_error => nil,
        :run_at => Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:24:06 UTC +00:00,
     :locked_at => Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:24:20 UTC +00:00,
     :failed_at => nil,
     :locked_by => "host:typhoon.local pid:84593",
    :created_at => Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:24:06 UTC +00:00,
    :updated_at => Tue, 02 Aug 2011 13:24:06 UTC +00:00
}
#<NoMethodError: undefined method `update_listed_package_states_for' for #<Class:0x007fe3771118d8>>
```

Comment: I'm also seeing this behaviour on lion. Sadly I don't have a solution yet but will post back if I find one.

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to do the same. I have my snow leopard machine still so the pain is still too small for me to dig for hours but I will reach that need soon I am sure.

Comment: Francois, did you ever figure this one out?

Comment: Are you using stock ruby? Tried using 1.8.7 installed via RVM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up fixing this for me was bumping up my gems and then resorting to bundle exec... to run cucumber & rspec.  Never really got to the bottom of the cause but this leads me to believe it was a stray gem being loaded that was causing the trouble.